# How can assign the color at black Up-Down pointing triangle VBA's language?

Tags: vba

i  have this text in vba's language and i have to edit to insert the black up/down pointing triangle depending if the data is increasing or decreasing..

```
Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[17]=""s"",IF(Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[16]-Filter_Corporate!R[-3]C[15]>0,""" & ChrW(&H25B2) & """,""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """), """")"
```

i tried to set up a if-cicle control but it doesn't woork

anybody can help me????
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after your line:

```
If [F5].Value = ChrW(&H25B2) Then
    [F5].Font.Color = vbGreen
ElseIf [F5].Value = ChrW(&H25BC) Then
    [F5].Font.Color = vbRed
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.  I note the reference style of the target cell is absolute, while the source cells are relative (but in a fixed worksheet).  Are there really two numbers, then an 's' in those source cells?

```
Debug.Print Range("Filter_Corporate!U2").Value, _
    Range("Filter_Corporate!V2").Value, _
    Range("Filter_Corporate!W2").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

THE FOLLOWING LINES TAKE VALUES FROM FILTERED DATA AND I SET UP A CYCLE IF. THIS CYCLE FOCUS ON_ 
IMPORTANCE SIGNIFICANT ABOUT VALUES AND THEN SET UP GREEN POINT UP TRIANGLE AND RED POINT DOWN TRIANGLE
THEN THE CODE IS EXTENDED TO THE COLUMN.

```
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF('Filter_A1!R[-1]C[15]=""s"",IF('Filter_A1!R[-1]C[14]-'Filter_Target Privati'!R[-1]C[13]>0,""" & ChrW   
(&H25B2) & """,""" & ChrW(&H25BC) & """), """")"


Range("H3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H3:H100"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H3:H100").Select


Range("H:H").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:=ChrW(&H25B2)

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
.Color = -11489280
.TintAndShade = 0
End With

 Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


 Range("H:H").Select
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, enter code hereOperator:=xlEqual, _
 Formula1:=ChrW(&H25BC)
 Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
 With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
 .Color = -16776961
 .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
 Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I HOPE TO BE USEFULL TO SOMEONE ELSE!!!